# Google Analytics: Configure Home Page Metrics To View All Sites Across All Accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I have several sites spread across four Google Analytics accounts.

On the homepage, it gives data from all sites across all GA accounts in the following metrics:

`Visits, Average Session Time, Bounce Rate, and Goal Conversion Rate:`

[image]

I'm trying to gather aggregated data of all sites from all accounts for **Page Views** and **Unique Visitors** (because I intend to compare these sites' results to IBM's coremetrics output for our sites recorded there... and CoreMetrics doesn't have Google Analytics metrics like `Visits`, `Average Session Time`, etc).

Is there a way to change the homepage metrics columns? I mean, I know I can do this in each individual site account by configuring the dashboard, but that won't allow me to compare all sites from all GA accounts.

Better yet, can I either:

- Create a dashboard of all sites spread across all accounts to graphically represent the data?
- Or, export the columns to CSV and create my own graphics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe metrics on the homepage are configurable.

If you're going to need to pull the data every week/month, I would look into the Google Analytics [magic script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic), which would allow you to pull in data from multiple accounts into Google Spreadsheets. From there, you can build a dashboard, etc. If you don't need to pull data regularly, then you could export the reports directly from Google and into a CSV, and then drop them into Excel and do your graphs, tables there.

Comment: Thanks Blexy! Unfortunately, Google Docs is blocked at work. Is there anyway to put analytics data into a regular CSV instead of a google app?

Comment: Have you looked at [Excellent Analytics](http://excellentanalytics.com/)? I believe they have a free version you could try out. This would get your GA data directly into Excel. It's a bit more cumbersome, but you could always schedule reports using GA via email.